# sklearn installed but unable to import

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

[image]

When I try to import sklearn it is giving the following error.

Please find the below error trace for more details:

```
C:\Users\Priyanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages> pip install sklearn                  Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in c:\users\priyanshu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in c:\users\priyanshu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from sklearn) (0.22)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.0 in c:\users\priyanshu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (1.17.2)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\priyanshu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.17.0 in c:\users\priyanshu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (1.3.1)
PS C:\Users\Priyanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages> python                               Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Priyanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
  File "C:\Users\Priyanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_show_versions.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._openmp_helpers import _openmp_parallelism_enabled
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The same error is fixed by installing sklearn below 0.22. Please try the below command.

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.21.3
```

Comment: thanks for the help but I upgraded my python from 32 bit to 64-bit version and that helped

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow & I hope this helps!

In windows, as you can see `DLL`s are of a bit dependency with Python Packages. You have installed `scikit-learn` but there could be some interdependencies you got missed.

Prefer installing `Anaconda` setup. It has a curated list of packages that ensures that installed packages work.

Link: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/